# How can I get list of gameobjects in a scene by scene name but only once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Inside GUILayout button:

```
if (GUILayout.Button("Test"))
{
    var selection = Selection.gameObjects.ToList();
    var scenesNames = ScriptsManager.ListScenes();
    List<Transform> objectsInScene = new List<Transform>();

    if (prefab != null && selection.Count > 0)
    {
        for (var i = selection.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            var selected = selection[i];
            for (int x = 0; x < scenesNames.Count; x++)
            {
                if (selected.scene.name == scenesNames[x])
                {
                    objectsInScene.AddRange(ScriptsManager.GetSceneObjects(scenesNames[x]));
                }
            }
        }
```

And the method GetSceneObjects:

```
public static List<Transform> GetSceneObjects(string sceneName)
{
    Scene s = SceneManager.GetSceneByName(sceneName);

    List<Transform> childs = new List<Transform>();
    GameObject[] gameObjects = s.GetRootGameObjects();

    for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!childs.Contains(gameObjects[i].transform))
            childs.Add(gameObjects[i].transform);
        foreach (Transform go in gameObjects[i].transform)
        {
            if (!childs.Contains(go))
                childs.Add(go);
        }
    }

    return childs;
}
```

In the method `GetSceneObjects`, I'm trying to filter out identical objects but it's not working.

If for example in the GUILayout button I selected in the Hierarchy 3 objects from one scene and 1 object from another scene I'm getting 16 objects in the List objectsInScene.

But that's wrong.

The 3 objects I selected in the first scene are all from the same scene so it should add to the List only 5 objects once since the first scene have overall 5 objects. But instead, it's adding 15 objects since it's selected object make it get all the 5 objects in the scene.

In the end, I have a List with 16 objects but it should be List only 6 objects.

The first scene has 5 objects, and the second scene has 1 object.

Comment: Also, stop using OnGui and start using [the new UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-ui).

Comment: @Draco18s I can use the new UI with EditorWindow script ?

Comment: I didn't know you were writing an editor window script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it wrong but quick fix would be to change

`List<Transform> objectsInScene = new List<Transform>();` to `HashSet<Transform> objectsInScene = new HashSet<Transform>();`

and

`objectsInScene.AddRange(ScriptsManager.GetSceneObjects(scenesNames[x]));` to `objectsInScene.UnionWith(ScriptsManager.GetSceneObjects(scenesNames[x]));`

In the end you could do `objectsInScene.ToList()` if List instance is required.